# Why is one eigenvalue of this matrix necessarily zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, independence

I have a 400x4096 matrix `M`. If I do M<sup>T</sup>M, I get a 4096x4096 matrix. If I find the eigenvalues of this matrix, there are 399 non-zero eigenvalues. Even if I change the values in the original matrices, I find that there are always 399 non-zero eigenvalues.

**What I Want To Know:**

1) I assume that the 399 comes from the 400 in the original matrix, and that two of the rows are not linearly independent, so we get 400 eigenvalues, of which one is zero. Is this the case?

2) If so, why are two of the rows linearly dependent? ie. why do we get 399 instead of 400?

Comment: Note that $M^TM$ has the same non-zero eigenvalues as the smaller matrix $MM^T$

Comment: It is not the case that every $400 \times 4096$ matrix has $399$ non-zero eigenvalues, so changing the values appropriately should give you something with $400$ non-zero eigenvalues.  Either there is something the software is doing incorrectly, there is some way in which you are using the software, or there is something you are not telling us about the specific way in which you "change the values of the original matrices".  In either case, we can't give a useful assessment without more information.

Comment: It's not necessarily **two** rows that are linearly dependent, rather the $400$ rows are linearly dependent.  Why that is the case depends on your matrix, which we don't know.

Comment: If the first $400$ columns of $M$ constitute an identity matrix, while all the remaining columns are zero, then $M^TM$ has a $400\times400$ identity matrix in the upper left corner and zeros everywhere else. So it has eigenvalue $1$ with multiplicity $400$, not just $399$.